# Change the color of a link over time (so that it doesn't begin a new cycle on refresh)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to change the color of a link over time cycling through rainbow colors. When you refresh the color should still be the same it was a moment ago, not begin a new cycle (so CSS animations haven't worked for me yet either).

I am trying to apply the color of this calculation to the hover function of a link.

```
  var h = ( 60 * ( color[0] + time ) % 360 ) / 360;
  materials[i].color.setHSL( h, color[1], color[2] );
  var time = Date.now() * 0.00005;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `color` array isn't defined anywhere. Also you are not passing a variable to `$(this).css("color");`. The Jquery CSS function works like this: `$(this).css("color", "#000000");` or `$(this).css("color", variable);`.

Comment: @WizardCoder I am trying to apply the color from the calculation to the color of the link on hover

Comment: This would require local state storage or a back-end solution. JavaScript isn't persistent. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

```js
var colors = [
  '#FF0000', // Red
  '#FF7F00', // Orange
  '#FFFF00', // Yellow
  '#00FF00', // Green
  '#0000FF', // Blue
  '#4B0082', // Indigo
  '#9400D3', // Violet
];

var link = document.getElementById('link');

function calculateColor() {
  var time = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  link.style.color = colors[time % colors.length];
}

calculateColor();
setInterval(calculateColor, 100);
```

```html
<p><a id="link" href="#">Link</a></p>
```

If you need another frequency instead of 1 second, you could keep the timestamp rounded until the next time interval... I don't know if I make myself clear, because I don't know how to explain it. It'd be something like:

```js
var colors = [
  '#FF0000', // Red
  '#FF7F00', // Orange
  '#FFFF00', // Yellow
  '#00FF00', // Green
  '#0000FF', // Blue
  '#4B0082', // Indigo
  '#9400D3', // Violet
];

var link = document.getElementById('link');

var freq = 5; // seconds
var time = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

function calculateColor() {
  var now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  var offset = now - time;
  time = offset > freq ? now : time;
  link.style.color = colors[time % colors.length];
}

calculateColor();
setInterval(calculateColor, 100);
```

```html
<p><a id="link" href="#">Link</a></p>
```

Comment: every time I refresh the link is a different color? maybe I'm implementing it wrong? it doesn't remain the same color on refresh & continue on from the same part of the sequence. the code I've pasted in my initial question is the code that changes the colors of some threejs particles. I want the link to match the color of the particles.

Comment: In the case of my code it'll depend on how long it takes to refresh since the frequency here is 1 second on the first case or 5 on the second. Anyway, my answer is just an approach that might help you (or not) but you shouldn't expect to get some piece of code that will work by just copying and pasting into your project. You need to actually understand what you're doing.

Comment: I appreciate that, but I've come to this website to ask a question as I don't know what I'm doing. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This can be cleaned up a little, but this should get you started. I'm assuming the hue is what you actually want to save since your method is using color[0] for the calculation. So I am saving hue, but you can modify this to fit your need. It uses web storage to save the hue: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

```
// init function(run on page load, either fresh or after refresh)
$(function() {
    var hue = null;

    // check if local storage supported
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        // check if hue saved
        if (sessionStorage.hue) {
            hue = sessionStorage.hue;
        }
    }
    // check if hue is still null, if so, it is a fresh page load 
    // or storage isn't supported and we need to calculate it
    if (!hue) {
        // call your hue function here
        hue = getNewHue();
    }
    // save hue
    saveHue(hue);
});

// run everytime the mouse hovers over your link
// you can convert this to an interval function like
// in Jordi's answer if you want
$('#colorlink').on('hover', function() {
    // get a new hue
    var hue = getNewHue();
    // call your hue function here
    saveHue(hue);
})

function saveHue(hue) {
    // set hue on link
    var hslText = "hsl(" + hue + "," + color[1] + "%," + color[2] + "%)";
    $('#colorlink').css({ color = hslText });

    // also saving this to update materials[i] as well
    // not sure if you still need this
    materials[i].color.setHSL(hue, color[1], color[2]);

    // save hue to storage in case of refresh
    sessionStorage.setItem('hue', hue);
}

function getNewHue() {
    return (60 * (color[0] + time) % 360) / 360;
}
```

Comment: this isn't working at all for me. I'm pasting it into my external js file - is that right?

Comment: Yes. Without the html I can't tell you what is wrong, but I'm guessing it has to do with the link element selector. Inside `$('link')` you should put whatever the selector is on the link you want to change colors, presumably, it is the same element as `materials[i]`, I just wasn't sure how you were selecting that element.

Comment: The materials[i] element is from a threejs background on my site. The particles rotate in color, so I want the links to match the color of the particles. I thought that applying the same function to the link color would work, but I can't figure it out. I've tried adding your code snippet to the js, with the correct selector `$('#colorlink a').mouseenter(function() {
    var hue = getNewHue();
    saveHue(hue);
})` but I'm doing something wrong

Comment: The html is simply `<p><a id="colorlink" href="#">ABOUT</a></p>`

Comment: @NPM I modified the `saveHue` function to set the color on the link. When you expect that you should see a color entry for it in your css after this runs. If you still have issues, can you add some console.logs to make sure it is actually running all the functions.